# Bootstrap 4: Align dynamically added columns

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, gutter

I am trying to use bootstrap 4 grid.
The number of cols vary in number and are added dynamically. It leads to adding more than 12 cols within a row(which is not ideal - but not sure how to deal with such scenarios when the cols are dynamically added).

The outcome: The grid works fine and rearranges the cols as expected. However, I think the gutter gets added **twice** for the inner cols. Refer to the image attached.

I searched the docs, used justify-space-between/around - but no luck

https://jsfiddle.net/8L3dt1xh/1/

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-6"> .. image .. </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-6"> .. image .. </div>
  ... many such divs .. 
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-6"> .. image .. </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-6"> .. image .. </div>
</div>
```

Any pointer on how to get uniform spacing between cols will be a great help.

[image]

Comment: Show us what's inside each column. I don't think the gutter would be doubled. The gap you see might due to the elements after the images.

Comment: @DavidLiang Added JSfiddle in the post. Please have a check

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to add a padding `15px` to both sides of the container which will give a consistent result throughout the rows, no matter how many items

```css
.row {
  padding: 0 15px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<section class="">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-6">
        <a href="/">
          <figure class="figure">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/850X150?text=X" style="height:150px" class="img-fluid rounded" alt="dummy">
            <figcaption class="figure-caption text-center">Check</figcaption>
          </figure>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-6">
        <a href="/">
          <figure class="figure">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/850X150?text=X" style="height:150px" class="img-fluid rounded" alt="dummy">
            <figcaption class="figure-caption text-center">Check</figcaption>
          </figure>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-6">
        <a href="/">
          <figure class="figure">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/850X150?text=X" style="height:150px" class="img-fluid rounded" alt="dummy">
            <figcaption class="figure-caption text-center">Check</figcaption>
          </figure>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-6">
        <a href="/">
          <figure class="figure">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/850X150?text=X" style="height:150px" class="img-fluid rounded" alt="dummy">
            <figcaption class="figure-caption text-center">Check</figcaption>
          </figure>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-6">
        <a href="/">
          <figure class="figure">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/850X150?text=X" style="height:150px" class="img-fluid rounded" alt="dummy">
            <figcaption class="figure-caption text-center">Check</figcaption>
          </figure>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-6">
        <a href="/">
          <figure class="figure">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/850X150?text=X" style="height:150px" class="img-fluid rounded" alt="dummy">
            <figcaption class="figure-caption text-center">Check</figcaption>
          </figure>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-4 col-6">
        <a href="/">
          <figure class="figure">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/850X150?text=X" style="height:150px" class="img-fluid rounded" alt="dummy">
            <figcaption class="figure-caption text-center">Check</figcaption>
          </figure>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would personally go for building a flexbox myself, rather than using the Bootstrap's Grid system, because then I can add my own paddings on the items and calculate an uniform spacing between them.

```html
<section class="items">
    <a href="#" class="item">
        <figure />
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="item">
        <figure />
    </a>
    ...
</section>
```

First of all, you want to make `.items` as a flexbox, displayed as a wrap-able row:

```
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";

.items {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

I'm using SASS here but you can see the generated CSS in the demo.

I also saw you had `.col-6`, `.col-sm-4`, etc classes on each column. You can replicate that by setting the width of the `.item` on each breakpoint:

```
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";

.items {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;

    .item {
        width: calc(100%/2);        // 2 per row 

        @include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
            width: calc(100%/3);    // 3 per row
        }

        @include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
            width: calc(100%/4);    // 4 per row
        }

        @include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
            width: calc(100%/6);    // 6 per row
        }
    }
}
```

Now it's time to calculate the gutter between two `.item`s. Indeed, if you add padding on each `.item`, the spacing between 2 of them will be doubled. But you can easily accommodate that by adding half of the gutter/spacing on their parent flexbox, `.items`.

It would be even easier if you're using SASS, because you can declare a variable for the gutter spacing you want and you can do the calculations based on that:

```
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/functions";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/variables";
@import "../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/mixins";

$items-gutter: 2rem;

.items {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    padding: $items-gutter/2;

    .item {
        padding: $items-gutter/2;
        width: calc(100%/2);        // 2 per row 

        @include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
            width: calc(100%/3);    // 3 per row
        }

        @include media-breakpoint-up(md) {
            width: calc(100%/4);    // 4 per row
        }

        @include media-breakpoint-up(lg) {
            width: calc(100%/6);    // 6 per row
        }
    }
}
```

That would add 1rem padding on the flexbox `.items`, and 1rem padding on each `.item`. That would make up total 2rem paddings around each item.

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/rv0knh8b/15/